# python sniffing TCP. What is the weird text in the end and can i get some information from it? Using scapy

Tags: python, tcp, packet-sniffers

example what i usually get and what i need always:

```
{'b': {'x': 'GameHandler', 'p': {'heroes': [2008369, 4943029]}, 'c': 'get.atm', 'r': 1}, 't': 'xt'}
```

what is this and what can i do with this?:

```
{'t': 'xt', 'b': {'r': -1, 'gz': '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'}}
```

code:

```
from scapy.all import * import json

while True:
    packet = sniff(count=1, filter='host 91.225.236.166')
    try:
        info = packet[0].load.decode('utf-8')
        info = info.replace('\x00', '')
        info = str(info)
        info = json.loads(info)
        print(info)
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is basically asking to reverse engineer a protocol without giving any kind of useful context. With sufficient context it might be on-topic at [reverseengineering.se], but not here. As for the data: this is some JSON compressed with zlib and encoded with base64.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.